Tensorflow fit won't take custom dataset, but throws error: ValueError: Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank
I'm trying to train a model previously working fine until recently. The fit function throws the error below:
    <ipython-input-20-01755a6ded38> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(
      2     dataset,
      3     epochs=100,
      4     verbose=1,
      5     batch_size=8)

1 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120             # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121             # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123         finally:
    124             del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/losses/loss.py in squeeze_or_expand_to_same_rank(x1, x2, expand_rank_1)
    105 def squeeze_or_expand_to_same_rank(x1, x2, expand_rank_1=True):
    106     """Squeeze/expand last dim if ranks differ from expected by exactly 1."""
--> 107     x1_rank = len(x1.shape)
    108     x2_rank = len(x2.shape)
    109     if x1_rank == x2_rank:

ValueError: Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.

I've tried passing just the x and y generated by the generator into fit and it works fine, so it's not a shape problem.
Here's a recreation of the error. The model is just a simple Sequential model:
model = keras.models.Sequential(
    [keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
     keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')]
)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

The dataset is generated from tf.data.Dataset.from_generator() as below:
#Random dataset
a = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randint(0,100, size=[10,10]))
    
#Data generator class
class DataGenerator:
   def __init__(self, data, ratio=3):
      self._ratio = ratio
      self._data = data
    
   def __call__(self):
      shape = tf.shape(self._data).numpy()
      x = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.randint(1000,100000, size=[shape[0] * self._ratio, shape[1]]))
      x = tf.concat([self._data, x], axis = 0)
      y = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random(shape[0]*(1 + self._ratio)))
    
      yield x, y


data_gen = DataGenerator(a, 3)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
            data_gen,
            output_signature=(
                tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,10), dtype=tf.int32),
                tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None), dtype=tf.float32)))

Model.fit() produced the error above:
model.fit(
    dataset,
    epochs=100,
    verbose=1,
    batch_size=8)

Here's a recreation of the error in Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1f7I2St2U3LxaWZZSTxT2xWN14gCZMBSE?usp=sharing

I have exactly the same problem with the custom generator in Dataset. I haven't found the reason yet, but I suspect it's because the generator is streaming (infinite)

What I did was reverting the Tensorflow version to 2.15.0... Not sure what they did this new update

The error specified occurs when the loss function receives tensors whose type differs from those specified when declaring the generator.
In your case, the output specification of your generator must contain int64 and float64 types.
data_gen = DataGenerator(a, 3)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
        data_gen,
        output_signature=(
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,10), dtype=tf.int64), # <- here
            tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float64))) # <- and here

After you change types, your Colab example will start working:

